# Why can't I reset the password for another user on my computer?

Tags: windows-10, passwords

I have another user on my Windows 10 computer, who has forgotten their password. According to [this article](https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/how-to-change-another-users-password-in-windows-10.html), I should be able to reset their password from the control panel, like so:

[image]

But here's what I see:
[image]

Notice that there is no "Change the Password" option. So how am I supposed to reset this user's password?

**UPDATE:** There must be something different about the configuration of this computer, because I don't have the "Local Users and Groups" section under "Computer Management" that @Akina suggested:

[image]

Where is the secret switch that allows me to manage other users on this computer?

FWIW, this is a home computer, so no network admins are involved here.

Comment: Does you account have administrative privileges on your machine?

Comment: @Seth Yes it does.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems that the account to which you are trying to change the password is not a local account. I cannot be sure of it though, since you obfuscated the second line of the user ID.

Only local accounts have their password stored on the computer, and only such accounts can have it changed the way [@Akina](https://superuser.com/a/1338837/606417) suggests.

- If you are using your Microsoft accounts to log in, you need to use Microsoft's lost password procedure.
- If you use Active Directory, tell your coworker to ask your company's IT support. Only domain admins can change AD account passwords.

You can tell your accounts use Active Directory if the second line in the user's profile is in the form `Corporate name\User name`.

---

Note: the normal procedure to chnage your password under AD is to press Ctrl+Alt+Del and choose "Change password", however, *you will need your old password*. Going to your support is only in case you have lost your password.

Comment: *It seems that the account to which you are trying to change the password is not a local account.* Oh, it seems you're right. I did not pay attention to it.

Comment: It's a local account. This is a home computer.

Comment: Unless...maybe the user is linked to a Microsoft account...?

Comment: Ha! That's it! The user's login is linked to their Microsoft account. I got them to login with their Microsoft Live password, and that did it. Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: @ShaulBehr You can have them configure a PIN for login, which is more secure than using the SSO password, and the PIN is stored locally.  Microsoft added support for letters and special characters to PINs, so it doesn't have to be numeric.

Answer (score 3):

- Right-click on the 'My computer' icon.
- Select 'Computer Management' (or Management).
- Select 'Local users and groups - Users'.
- Select user, right-click, 'Set password'.

PS. If you have no admin priveleges, you'll be asked for an authentication as Administrator.

Comment: or right click on "Start" then "Computer Management"

Comment: @chloesoe Of course, there is a list of methods to open this applet. The method I describe seems to be the most simple for a common user.

Comment: Please see my update. I don't have that option!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to secretly change the password
1. get on command prompt using "Admin"
2. when prompted type in "net user"
It will show you all the users accounts.
3.type in "net user", username and new password
I highly suggest only using it when it is your LAST option to prevent from being permanently locked out of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find "local users and groups" in the control panel on a windows 10 system, try opening it by entering "lusrmgmt.msc" into the search or a command line window. You might have to start it with administrative privileges, either by using a "run as..." option in the right click menu, or starting a cmd.exe in that way.